# c return value through parameters

Tags: c

So, I'm puzzled with this issue for over an hour.

Background:

I have an implementation of kernel threads in [xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6.html) that I want to test.

The threads communicate return values via a field ret_val.

Each thread saves the return value in **the other thread's** ret_val (because it can technically be de-allocated after returning a value).

I have two parts in my code that do not work as I'd expect.

*Notes:
the **field** proc->ret_val is of type **void****
the **field** proc->has_waiting is of type **struct proc ***

Part 1 (this is the part that stores the return value in the process's struct):

```
// store value in WAITING THREAD's ret_val.
    (*proc->has_waiting->ret_val) = (void*)ret_val;
    cprintf("(t_exit)process %d is taking the return value %s\n", proc->pid, (char *)ret_val);
    cprintf("(t_exit)process %d now has return value from %d -> %s\n", proc->has_waiting->pid, proc->pid, (char *)(*proc->has_waiting->ret_val));
```

This ^ part's job is to store a value in a process's ret_val (inside the "has_waiting" field, which is a pointer to a structure of a process).

This seems to work because the prints indicate the value is indeed saved.

Part 2 (this is the part that tries to read the process's struct ret_val field):

```
cprintf("(t_join) process %d is taking the return value %s\n", proc->pid, (char *)(*proc->ret_val));
            * ret_val = proc->ret_val; // it's t's duty to set proc's ret_val
```

This ^ part's job is to restore the value from within the struct's structure (ret_val field) before it's destroyed.

Part 2 does not work, the ret_val field is empty.

I've tried all sorts of casting manipulations but it seems I misunderstand a basic concept here.

I've verified the struct I'm addressing is the correct struct by printing out it's id (unique).

The value that I'm passing (in ret_val) is a static string (char*) I've defined in the main function that creates the processes (I wanted to make sure it's not destroyed or something).

I'd appreciate any help. If further information is needed let me know.

Comment: This is really hard to read. I suggest isolating your problem in a more readable contrived example instead of pasting code you're working with here.

Comment: I've added some information. If you could tell me which part is most confusing I'll try and improve it

Comment: Returning value through parameters is easy. Pass a pointer to where the caller wants the called to store the returning value. Called function then: a) checks for null, b) dereferences pointer to return storage and set that dereferenced storage to approproiate value. The caller can then access that stored value through the pointer it knows about. If you are doing this and ending up with nothing, the normal proble is that a local value in the called is being stored, and that is falling out of scope so doesn't exist by the time the caller checks on the stored return value.

Comment: THANKS! I had problem that was resolved by following the referencing chain! THANKS A LOT. @StarPilot

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly, you "return" the value via this field:

```
proc->has_waiting->ret_val
```

but you reference it via this field:

```
proc->ret_val
```

You should be using the same reference in both places.

EDIT: How about simplifying this and making `ret_val` a `char *`?

Comment: This is confusing, but "has_waiting" is also a process and it's HIS ret_val I'm trying to read in part 2.

Sorry for the confusion. (part 1 -> stores into "has_waiting" process, part 2 -> reads from the has_waiting process, when proc is the "has_waiting" process).

Comment: So you're saying that `proc` is really `proc->has_waiting`?

Comment: there are many threads. proc is the current thread.

In the first part a thread (we'll call it thread1) is setting ret_val of another thread.

In part 2 another thread (we'll call it thread2) is trying to read it.

thread2 is also thread1->has_waiting (I've verified this as far as I can tell).